# Mathematica Implementations of Post Quantum Cryptography Algorithms?

Tags: functions, cryptography

Mathematica supports several cryptographic commands like [Encrypt](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Encrypt.html), [Decrypt](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Decrypt.html) and others.

This includes support for asymmetric signature ciphers like RSA and Elliptic curves and symmetric ciphers like "Blowfish", "CAST5", "DES", "IDEA", "AES128", "AES192", "AES256".

NIST is working on updates for Post Quantum Cryptography (PQC) and has selected new algorithms like CRYSTALS-Kyber (KEM) and CRYSTALS-Dilithium (Signatures). They also added LMS and XMSS and may add others as a result of further rounds. You can see a list and "C" implementations at [Open Quantum Safe (OQS)](https://openquantumsafe.org/liboqs/algorithms/). They also include wrappers for other languages.

My question, does anyone know of implementations of [Kyber](https://openquantumsafe.org/liboqs/algorithms/kem/kyber) and [Dilithium](https://openquantumsafe.org/liboqs/algorithms/sig/dilithium) in Mathematica or any of the other new algorithms?

At some point, MMA will likely update to support these new algorithms, but I was wondering if anyone had pointers to anything people implemented presently?